# Test Time Augmentation throwing a value error

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, fast-ai

I am trying to use the Test Time Augmentation on my Classifier:

```
log_preds,y = learn.TTA(scale=1.1, ds_type=DatasetType.Valid, with_loss=True)
```

And this is the error that it threw:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f33d9737819a> in <module>()
----> 1 log_preds,y = learn.TTA(scale=1.1, ds_type=DatasetType.Valid, with_loss=True)
      2 probs = np.mean(np.exp(log_preds),0)
      3 
      4 accuracy(probs, y)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Initially, I tried to find a way to use my custom test set in TTA but couldn’t figure out how to do it and DatasetType.Test was throwing an error so I decided to go with DatasetType.Valid and after running 8 epochs, I got the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicate that `learn.TTA` returns more than 2 values,but you only got `log_preds`and `y` for them.
You want to find out what exactly does `learn.TTA` return

Comment: In the [source code](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/fastai/vision/tta.py#L43), we can find out that this function returns 2 tensors if `with_loss` is `False` and 3 otherwise. And in your code, `with_loss` is `True`, that means `learn.TTA` returns 3 tensors.Try:`log_preds,y,_loss = learn.TTA(scale=1.1, ds_type=DatasetType.Valid, with_loss=True)`